# Trouble adding JMenuBar to extended JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, menubar

My `Main` class extends `JFrame` and for some reason, I can't get my `MenuBar` and items to show correctly. Is there a special way of adding the menubar?

```
public class Main extends JFrame
{
// DRIVER
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main window = new Main();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

private JMenuBar menuBar; 

private JMenu menu,
          menuFile;

private JMenuItem menuItemNew,
              menuItemExit;
...

// CONSTRUCTOR
public Main()
{

    initializeWindow();
    initializeMenu();
}

private void initializeWindow()
{
    setTitle(TITLE + " " + VERSION);
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    backgroundColor = new GradientBackground(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}

private void initializeMenu()
{
    // Menubar
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 72);
    menuBar.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    menuBar.setVisible(true);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    // Menu title
    menu = new JMenu();
    menu.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    menuBar.add(menu);



    // File Option
    menuFile = new JMenu("FILE");
    menuFile.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    menuFile.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    menuBar.add(menuFile);

    // New File
    menuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    menuItemNew.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    menuItemNew.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    menuFile.add(menuItemNew);

    // New File
    menuItemExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuItemExit.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    menuItemExit.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    menuItemExit.setEnabled(true);
    menuFile.add(menuItemExit);

    getContentPane().add(menuBar);
} // END initializeMenu()
```

Comment: [`setJMenuBar(menuBar);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)) is enough, no need to do `getContentPane().add(menuBar);`.

Comment: 1- try calling initializeMenu first. 2- Why are you adding the menuBar to the contentPane?

Comment: Remove that call:  `getContentPane().add(menuBar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I think that you looking for [JFrame.setMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMenuBar%28java.awt.MenuBar%29) instead of `add(JMenuBar)`
- there no required `getContentPane()` for Java 5 and newer version
- don't to extend `JFrame`, create this `Object` as `local variable`